# Applets & client certificate authentication

Tags: firefox, authentication, applet, client-certificates

I have an applet that loads its jar dependencies from a server using SSL + client certificate authentication.

The web page that loads the applet is already authenticated using a client certificate.

However, when the applet starts up, the JVM process (separate from the browser) brings up a dialog for certificate selection. These certificates, as it turns out, are read from the java client cert keystore:

- %USERPROFILE%\Application
  Data\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\trusted.clientcerts
  (Windows XP/2000)
- %USERPROFILE%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\trusted.clientcerts
  (Windows 7)

I want to avoid forcing the user to import his/her certificate into this keystore. Instead, I want to make the JVM search for the certificate in the Firefox's certificate keystore.

Is this doable? Real-world examples would be highly appreciated!